# How to create a model field that is an average of all of another foreign key model' field. Ex: avg rating field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have two models. Fiction model that can be any movie, book, tv series or something similar. I have another model that is a review that contain review like fields for example: reviewer, rating, description.
What I want to do is the following:
Have Two extra fields in the fiction model that are:

1. number of reviews
2. average of review ratings

I was able to add them as integer and float fields and then changed them whenever a new review was added, edited, or deleted but there are two issues.

1. Adding reviews from the admin won't be accounted for
2. I just feel like that is not the best approach and I feel like there is a more sensible approach for the fields to be automatically filled from the review model.
   Here are the two models as well as how I implemented the api views.

fiction models.py

```
    from django.db import models

    from stream.models import StreamPlatform


   class Fiction(models.Model):
    """
    Model that encopasses a Movie, TV Series, book or similar
    """
    MOVIE       = 1
    TV_SERIES   = 2
    BOOK        = 3
    PODCAST     = 4

    TYPE = (
        (MOVIE, 'Movie'),
        (TV_SERIES, 'TV-Series'),
        (BOOK, 'Book'),
        (PODCAST, 'Podcast')
    )


    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    avg_rating = models.FloatField(default=0)
    number_rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    platform = models.ForeignKey(
        StreamPlatform, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
        related_name='fictions',
        null = True
        )
    type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        choices = TYPE,
        default = MOVIE
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Review models.py

```
    from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from fiction.models import Fiction

class Review(models.Model):
    """
    model for fiction reviews from users
    """
    reviewer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(5)])
    fiction = models.ForeignKey(Fiction, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="reviews")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null = True, blank =True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.rating) + " | " + str(self.fiction)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['reviewer', 'fiction']
        ordering = ['-created']
```

review views.py

```
    from watchmate.permissions import IsAdminOrReadOnly, IsOwnerOrReadOnly
from rest_framework import generics, mixins
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly

from django.db.utils import IntegrityError

from fiction.models import Fiction

from .models import Review
from .serializers import ReviewSerializer

class ReviewList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAdminOrReadOnly]
    # queryset = Review.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReviewSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        return Review.objects.filter(fiction=pk)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        fiction = Fiction.objects.get(pk=pk)

        reviewer = self.request.user

        # check if user has already reviewd this fiction
        # review = Review.objects.filter(fiction=fiction, reviewer=reviewer)
        # if review.exists():
        #     raise ValidationError("You have already reviewed this fiction")
        
        try:
            serializer.save(fiction=fiction, reviewer=reviewer)

            if fiction.number_rating == 0:
                fiction.avg_rating = serializer.validated_data['rating']
            else:
                fiction.avg_rating = (serializer.validated_data['rating']+fiction.avg_rating)/2

            fiction.number_rating += 1
            fiction.save()


        except IntegrityError:
            raise ValidationError("You have already reviewed this fiction") 


class ReviewDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Review.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReviewSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrReadOnly]


    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        instance = self.get_object()
        pk = self.kwargs.get('fiction_pk')
        fiction = Fiction.objects.get(pk=pk)
        # calculate overall rating sums
        total_rating = fiction.avg_rating*fiction.number_rating
        # subtract old rating
        total_rating -= instance.rating
        # add new rating
        total_rating += serializer.validated_data['rating']
        # calculate new fiction avg rating and save it
        fiction.avg_rating = total_rating/fiction.number_rating
        fiction.save()
        super().perform_update(serializer)

    def perform_destroy(self, instance):
        instance = self.get_object()
        pk = self.kwargs.get('fiction_pk')
        fiction = Fiction.objects.get(pk=pk)
        # calculate overall rating sums
        total_rating = fiction.avg_rating*fiction.number_rating
        # subtract old rating
        total_rating -= instance.rating
        # decrease fiction reviews by one
        fiction.number_rating -= 1
        # calculate new fiction avg rating and save it
        fiction.avg_rating = total_rating/fiction.number_rating
        fiction.save()
        super().perform_destroy(instance)
```

The logic for adding a new reviews is not 100% correct but never mind it. I just want to know how to be able to implement this logic at models and field level so it can also be possible to add reviews using admin and still be able to see changes

Comment: Please *don't* work with fields. You can work with properties, or annotations, but do *not* materialize aggregated data in the database.

Comment: Is it possible to show me how to add such a property or annotations? I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

As said in Willem's comment, you can use @property. Here is an example from the official documentation:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    birth_date = models.DateField()

def baby_boomer_status(self):
    "Returns the person's baby-boomer status."
    import datetime
    if self.birth_date < datetime.date(1945, 8, 1):
        return "Pre-boomer"
    elif self.birth_date < datetime.date(1965, 1, 1):
        return "Baby boomer"
    else:
        return "Post-boomer"

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        "Returns the person's full name."
        return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone wanted a solution to such a problem that is how I solved mine by adding a property to method just like @Willem Van Onsem and @Mhamed Bendenia said.

```
@property
def number_of_ratings(self):
    return self.reviews.count()

@property 
def average_rating(self):
    return self.reviews.aggregate(Avg('rating'))['rating__avg']
```

This way I dont have to write the logic myself in every view